# How to AVOID completion while pasting a `tab`?

Tags: linux, shell, readline

I build an executable like bash with readline. It provides completion when I type `tab`.
When I copy a `tab` and paste on it, it still does complete. That isn't I'm hoping for.

The only setting of readline is:

```
rl_completion_entry_function = CmdGenerator;
```

I could provide details of `CmdGenerator` if it matters.

I hope `tab` is like a general charator like `space` or alpha when I paste it.

I tried to paste a `tab` in postgres `psql`, it didn't complete. On this environment, I did so in `bash`, it also didn't complete while others environments' bash do complete.

Comment: First your question is unclear, because you tag it _shell_, which means 'POSIX shell', and POSIX shell does not have completion. Then, this is not a question about programming and should not be posted here. You can ask this at [su], but please fix your tags.

Comment: This is very dependent on which terminal you're using. Some send information about whether a paste operation has started or ended; others don't share the information so all, so the program running within the terminal has no way of knowing.

Comment: The feature you want in readline is called "bracketed paste", but since it's on by default, more likely you're using a terminal that isn't configured to support it (or doesn't even have the relevant feature available to configure in the first place), and as a configuration issue rather than a code/development problem, that's not something we can help you with here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the [bracketed paste](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracketed-paste) feature isn't working in your terminal, here is a work around:

Use your `$EDITOR` to edit the command line using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>x</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>e</kbd>. Paste the data into your editor, save and quit.

If the editor is Vim, you might want `:set paste` to turn on paste mode, to avoid the paste being reformatted by your auto-indent settings and whatnot.

Comment: It works! The point is brackedted-paste setting!